# how to make Wine GUI elements look like modern Windows elements

Tags: windows, wine, gui

I started using Wine to run Windows apps on Ubuntu, but I see that the style of User Interface elements like buttons etc. is too old, like the buttons of windows 98, is there a way to make it like Windows 7 or 8??

Comment: How to improve the font's appearance: http://askubuntu.com/questions/219791/improve-gui-appearance-of-wine-applications

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the EXACT details, but when you do "winecfg" there is an option for "Themes" under one of the tabs.  If you can get yourself to an XP or Win 7 Machine, go into c:/windows/resources (or it might be /system32/resources/) and you will find a msstyles folder or files.  You need to copy those items.  Load up the luna one in XP.  It will then give you options like in XP what colors you want.

Also this helps, but the forums are down, but you can enable font anti aliasing with a script.  Google "antialiasing wine" and you might find it posted somewhere else.