# Wine: How can I make Wine applications look like Windows 8?

Tags: windows, wine, windows-8, themes, gui

I just installed Wine and I realized the applications look terrible. I wanted the look and feel of Windows 8 on my Wine applications, how can I go about doing this? Thanks!

Comment: This shouldn't be a duplicate. - I am the OP of the question [Improve GUI appearance of Wine applications](https://askubuntu.com/q/219791/47206) and I can say that the meaning of my question was not relating to Windows 10. While the scope of my question is larger and *could* have encompassed this one, that  is  **not** necessarily the case. Nor do I see any answer under my question which would correspond to the intention of this one, no matter what the answer here says.

Comment: In what way the answers under my question have answered your question here? If you think they do, then you should change your question here: because nothing there revolves around Windows8/10 appearance.

Comment: @cipricus The way I see it, the accepted answer on the called duplicate mentions GTK theming in Wine which would seem to be exactly what this is looking for. I don't think it's too much of a leap from that to [here](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/02/windows-8-metro-gtk-theme)

Comment: @ElderGeek -  so, the answer would be the "windows 8" GTK theme presented in the link (which is not yet mentioned in my answer, but which could be added. Feel free to edit it accordingly.) - What I find problematic is the use of gtk themes in Wine: **it only works with winehq-staging**, which cannot be used with playonlinux.

Comment: @cipricus Rather than **bolding** a statement in a comment, why not [edit] that information into your post along with how you determined that which could feasibly get your question re-opened.

Comment: @ElderGeek - I have edited the answer under this question to add the link on the Windows 8 GTK theme.

Comment: @ElderGeek - in th edited form, the below answer links to the larger aspect of GTK themes for wine covered under the other question. So now I guess this can stay as a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219791/improve-gui-appearance-of-wine-applications) (really useful) or at this [article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/09/omg-5-five-ways-to-make-wine-apps-feel-native-in-ubuntu) (though it's a bit outdated, it could sill work)

An idea would be to use GTK themes for wine, namely a specific Windows 8 GTK theme. Details [here](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/02/windows-8-metro-gtk-theme), as initially posted in a comment above by @ElderGeek.

But gtk themes for wine can be used only with the `winehq-staging` package.