# Fixing colors in Windows-based programs running Wine

Tags: 18.04, wine, customization

I am running NTP v.7.2/Fv under Ubuntu 18.04, using Wine 4.*. I am trying a set-up like https://askubuntu.com/a/756781/190436. It works, except I need to change the highlight color on the menus. Right now it looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/FiRZvk9. I just need to change the blue-colored highlight to something I can see through. I am using the winecfg file. I even found the menu highlight, as shown here https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZpSv.jpg, and changed the color to a light gray, as shown. However, after pressing the 'Apply' button, it doesn't take.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks,
Lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and renamed the .wine directory to .wine-bkup. The I ran winecfg, which created a new .wine directory. I then copied the programs to the new directory and it's back to 'normal' now.