# how to make wine looks like my desktop colour scheme using WINETRICKS in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: wine, themes, colors, winetricks

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit. I notice a post **[What can be done to make Wine look more integrated into Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175868/what-can-be-done-to-make-wine-look-more-integrated-into-unity)**, in the post it was mentioned that I can make wine looks like my `Desktop's colour scheme` using `winetricks`. I was wondering if any one can give me the step by step instruction how to **make wine looks like my desktop colour scheme** using **winetricks** it would be a great help for me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it using winetricks but you can using winecfg

here is how:
http://archive09.linux.com/feature/123854

Comment: The actual answer would be helpful, even a brief paste (since you already cited the source)